# How to load CollectionView without Storyboard

Tags: ios, collectionview

I'm new to iOS development. I need to use a CollectionView without using Storyboard and this view has to be load in a tab. Is this possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ya. you can create it programmatically

```
-(void)loadView
{
 [super loadView];

 UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
 self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds  collectionViewLayout:layout];
 self.collectionView.delegate=self;
 self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
 [self.collectionView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

 [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
    forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];


[self.view addSubView:self.collectionView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a UIViewController subclass that implements UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate like this:

```
@interface MyViewController:UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@end
```

then in the **.m** file you implement the required [UICollectionViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UICollectionViewDelegate) and [UICollectionViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UICollectionViewDataSource) Methods

and override -[UIViewController viewDidLoad] like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UICollectionView *collectionView = [UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  collectionView.delegate = self;
  collectionView.dataSource = self;
  [self.view addSubview:collectionView];
}
```

Comment: See more here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html